# About valuation and domination

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm trying to understand different formulation of domination. Taking a field $K$ and two surjectives valuations $v$ and $w$ on it, TFAE:

1. $v=w$
2. $\mathcal{O}_v=\mathcal{O}_w$
3. $\mathcal{O}_v\supseteq\mathcal{O}_w$ and $\mathfrak{m}_v\cap\mathcal{O}_w=\mathfrak{m}_w$
4. $\mathcal{O}_v\supseteq\mathcal{O}_w$ and $\mathfrak{m}_v\supseteq\mathfrak{m}_w$

I think that's ok with that.

I'd like to have some description with uniformizer, for example

5. For all uniformizer $t_w$ for $w$ one has $v(t_w)>0$
6. For one uniformizer $t_w$ for $w$ one has $v(t_w)>0$

But such things would be equivalent with

7. $\mathfrak{m}_v\supseteq\mathfrak{m}_w$

Is that true, how prove that?

Comment: Do you assume that all valuations are discrete of rank $1$?

Comment: @CaptainLama Yes, my context is non singular curves that is $K/k$ transcendance degree 1, $k$ algebraically closed, and the valuations $v$ are discrete valuations (so rank 1) with $v(k^*)=0$